# jQuery - How to drop content to concrete position into INPUT?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm solving such a problem with Drag&Drop via jQuery.
I have a simple HTML where there are MARK elements inside the LABEL, which I make draggable. Then I want to transfer these elements to INPUT (text). For CSS using PicoCSS.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("mark").draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $('input[type="text"]').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            this.value += ui.draggable.text();
            this.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<label for="MF">
    Any information about XYZ... Drag and drop to input: <mark>Item1</mark>, <mark>Item 2</mark>,<mark>Item 3</mark>
    <input type="text" id="MF" name="MF" placeholder="Drop there" required>
</label>
```

I can do that thanks to the code, but DROP always puts the content at the end of INPUT. Is there any way to modify the code to insert content at a specific position of INPUT?
It may be that there is a string in the INPUT, e.g. "Yesterday I met ? and told me that...". And I need to drag the text from the MARK with the mouse to the question mark, and the text will be inserted (dropped) at that position to the question mark. Unfortunately, so far it works by drop (insert) only at the end. The need is to keep everything in forms, the data will be retrieved from the DB, further processed and stored again in the DB.

You can run it there - https://codepen.io/vontrips/pen/jOYzGOM

Comment: Of course it "drops" at the end, when all you do is `this.value += ...`. You would have to split the already existing value at some position, and insert your new dropped text in between the two parts. But determining the right position to split, won't be that easy. You would have to find a way to determine the "position" of each character of your existing value, to compare that against your drop coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, of course I know that `+=` will cause an addition to the end of INPUT. For me, the problem is just determining where the cursor is, mean where the text should be inserted. This is the very thing I need help with.